# html images in table with no space

Tags: html, css, image

I have an html table in which I am placing images side by side inside the td's. How can I get it so that there is no space at all between each image?  By default all browsers seem to put in a small space despite 0 padding and margin on each table element. I am not specifying a width on the td's so by default it takes up the width of the image inside of it.

i.e:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img ... /></td> //no space between the td's
    <td><img ... /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should post your CSS, even if it is simple...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply this css:

```
td, tr, img  { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

This resets all spaces to 0.

Answer (score 12):

One more thing that can avoid unwanted space between images:

```
<td style="line-height:0;">
```

Comment: This is the only solution works for me, tried to set all other `spacing`, `padding`, `border`... without success

Answer (score 2):

cellspacing and cellpadding should be 0 on the table.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><img></td> 
    <td><img></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `cellpadding`, `border`, and `cellspacing` attributes for the HTML `table` tag. If you are using XHTML or CSS, then check out the corresponding styles - `border-collapse`, `padding`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

On my situation, I am trying to continue coding photoshop / imageready splitted html (generated via slice tool or save for web).

If table have a "height" attribute and you replace some images with shorter content, table maintain height adding mysterios gaps between images.

All I have to remove the height. Simple and stupid, but this is a situation can happen.