# How do I remove border from HTML table in IE?

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a webpage containing a 1x10 table where each cell has no explicitly defined value but only a style having a content property, like so:

```
.dm_active_image {
  height: 16px;
  float: left;
  content: URL('../Images/DM-Active.png');
}
```

The above works fine in Chrome but in IE my table looks like this:
[image]

I don't understand why the border-like line is displayed. I have tried every combination of border related properties in my CSS but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: Here is the HTML tag for the table.

```html
<table class="mGridDisease" id="DisplayHealthData" style="border-width: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;" rules="all" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>
```

Comment: I'm guessing your table has a dark background. If so, this is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/3825500/215552 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/11117950/215552

Comment: You've tried border: none; yet? or border-collapse:collapse; on the table

Comment: @StefanBob - yes I have - at the table, row and cell levels :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - You the man! The second of your references had the answer - "display: block".